# Что надо сделать чтоб исправить эту ошибку в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

[image: Вот код]

Пожалуйста, помогите исправить ошибку

> Assets\script2.cs(11,19): error CS0117: 'Input' does not contain a
> definition for 'Getkey'

в коде, который на картинке.

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос в виде текста. Это правило такое.

Comment: "Код из интернета не работает". Первое, что вы должны сделать, увидев такую ошибку, проверить, правильно ли написано название метода. И код текстом надо вставлять. Лучше писать код самостоятельно, а не копипастить глючные скрипты из интернета 100-летней давности. Когда вы пишете код сами, студия не позволит вам допускать такие ошибки и будет правильно подсказывать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто: GetKey - функция состоящая из 2х слов, каждое слово в функции пишется с большой буквы.

Answer (score 0):

GetKey пишется с двумя большими буквами, поэтому и ошибка